# How to curl an xml in groovy?

Tags: xml, groovy

I'm currently trying to curl an xml file through groovy:

```
def command = "curl -H \"Accept:  application/xml\" ${path}" 
def process = command.execute() 
process.waitFor()
```

When I try to execute this script, the output has no xml formatting (as in, there are no xml tags, just the contents) and I also get

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application; Name or service not known
```

I tried running the same command directly in the terminal and it works fine there.

Comment: What is the content of `path`?

Comment: @Jens just a url

Comment: But it loooks like there is the problem: *Could not resolve host: application; Name or service not known* If `application` the correct server name? Do you have dns access?

Comment: @Jens It does seem that way, but as I said: The script does generate output, but without xml formatting.

Comment: Without to seeing the output it is hard what you get, but I guess that are not the data you expect. I think this is output from curl itself, because the error message stated that it can not find the service you try to call

Comment: @Jens technically it is the expected data, but it lacks any xml formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace:

```
def command = "curl -H \"Accept:  application/xml\" ${path}"
```

With

```
def command = ['curl', '-H', 'Accept:  application/xml', path]
```

Comment: It works,  but why?

Comment: When you use the String based execute method, something along the way (not sure what) guesses how to split the string into parameters. It was doing it wrong. It's always better to use the list form of execute, and this specifies the parameters where you need them